# Laravel 5.8. How to upload file?

Tags: html, laravel

I have simple Form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('company.store') }}">
    Logo: <br>
    <input name="logo" type="file"><br>
```

In my controller i try to save image with

```
$file = $request->file('logo')->store('avatars');
```

but i have error

```
 "Call to a member function store() on null"
```

`dd($request->file('logo');` shows `'null'`

How to reach file to save it?

Comment: https://youtu.be/Q6iL3u4IZgs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To upload a file you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to you opening form tag:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('company.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If you don't include it then only the file name will be submitted  and will cause

`$request->file('logo')`

to return `null` because it isn't a file it's a string.

Comment: I linked `storage` to public directory with `php artisan storage:link`, but i can't show images from there. If i use `<img src="{{ asset ('storage/app/avatars/LOW6Fc2TBH8UoexcXLntQkzncXSDN6OsIt7KLbiG.jpeg') }}">` image doesn't shows. What i do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

uploading file need a enctype="multipart/form-data"

```html
      <form action="{{ route('company.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
             class="form-material">
               {{csrf_field()}}
          <div class="form-body">         
                 <h3 class="card-title">upload image</h3>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">image 1</label>
                <input type="file" name="image_path" class="form-control">
             </div>
          </div>
    </form>



Your Controller should look like this .


public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,['image_path'=> 'required|image']);

        $company = new Company();
        if($request->hasFile('image_path'))
        {
      $company->image_path= $request->file('image_path')->store('company','public');
        }
        
        $company->save();

          return back()->with('success', 'Done!');

    }
```

Comment: Your code store image on public folder successfully but it returns xampp's tmp folder path in return in `$company->image_path` which should be the name of file which is actually stored in public folder.

Comment: when u want to use the image_path  you should do this >>

{{url('/storage/'.$company->image_path);}}

then it will work

Comment: sorry, your example works fine i have got name of file like `phph45.tmp` because of file object of laravel but your example returns file name with the path, but most of we need only filename so i have used `$request->file('image')->hashName()` and it is working, thanks.